# Change the background color of a cell mail template with VBA from Excel

Tags: html, vba, email

I have a mail template with a table in it.

I already changed a lot of things within the mail using the replace method.

The problem is I'd like to change the background color of an existing cell in the template. So far I've been able to create a cell with the background color I want but not quite what I need.

I use the **Htmlbody** method.

If any of you have an idea or a solution it would be much appreciated.

Comment: did you fully code the template on VBA before creating the mail that contains it ? If so, you can easily change the backround color of a cell in the table. Show any code you have done so far related to the table please

Comment: Hello no i am using a template that has been made with outlook. I use call the template and replace values with ones from the excel file. But for one specific value i'd like to change the BG color of the cell.

Comment: can you show the code you've wrote in order to "call the template and replace values" ? It would be easier to help you out

Comment: Is this vba or html question?

Answer (score 0):

Use inline CSS to change the color as it the most priority. You can use it in following manner.

```
<table>
  <td style='background-color:red'></td>
</table>
```

This will change your td color to red. 
This is different from using bgcolor in HTML.

Comment: Thanks i tried this but it wont change the bgcolor of the cell i want, it creates me a new cell :(